# How to use blazor webassembly css isolation feature?

Tags: css, blazor, webassembly, isolation

I have a Blazor WebAssembly project BlazorApp2 with following project structure
[image]

My head section in index.html :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorApp2</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default-base.css">
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp2.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script>
        window.MathJax = {
            tex: {
                macros: {
                    ceec: ['{\\fbox #1}\\,', 1],
                    ceece: ['\\underline{\\  {\\fbox{#1 }}\\  }', 1]
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>
```

My index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp2.Components
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<Gap2 />
```

Gap2.razor:

```
<h3>Gap</h3>
<span class="gap">@Text</span>
@code {
    private string Text { get; set; } = "Z";
}
```

Gap2.razor.css

```
span.gap {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 4ex;
    min-height: 2ex;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

But Page Index shown as:
[image]

We can see the "Z" under "Gap" DO NOT have background-color #ddd.

Why Css Isolation do not work?

Comment: What style does the developer console show?